# CKEDITOR checkDirty before Destroy

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, destroy

I have web app which created and manages support tickets.  As such multiple tabs can be open at a time on a single page within a browser and in each tab is an instance of CKEDITOR.  Tabs can be opened and closed as needed and when a tab is closed any CKEDITOR instance within the tab is destroyed.

The code below allows for the checking of changes in any of the CKEDITOR instances when navigating away from a page as a whole:

```
function beforeUnload( evt ) {
    for ( var name in CKEDITOR.instances ) {
        if ( CKEDITOR.instances[ name ].checkDirty() )
            return evt.returnValue = "You will lose the changes made in the editor.";
    }
}
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    window.addEventListener( "beforeunload", beforeUnload, false );
} else {
    window.attachEvent( "onbeforeunload", beforeUnload );
}
```

This works great, however, if a tab on the page containing a CKEDITOR instance is closed I want to do a checkDirty before destroying the CKEDITOR instance.

What I am looking for is the ability to detect the 'destroy' event on a CKEDITOR instance and then check that instance with checkDirty.  What I can't find is a way to detect the 'destroy' event.

Would appreciate any help here please.

Comment: how are these tabs managed? Just to be clear, you mean tabs within a single dom not different browser tabs and page instances..correct?

Comment: Correct, they are bootstrap tabs. All within a single DOM, not different browser tabs and not within different page instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`contentDomUnload` event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDomUnload) of the CKEditor for that:

```
for (var name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].on('contentDomUnload', function() {
        // Do here whatever you need
        if (this.checkDirty()) {
            // The instance is dirty
        }
    });
}
```

The event is fired before the content DOM structure is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.